# Ksh Script automatically calling another script in /usr/bin

Tags: unix

I am executing a ksh script named abs.ksh located at /app/fao.... which connects to a server, 
But the server is receiving a script named "ksh" which is present in /usr/bin...
I am not calling any script called ksh in abs.ksh(sorry cannot paste the code).

Also this happens only when the script is run in debug mode.
In non debug mode it works fine.

Can anyone give me a hint of what might be happening here.

Comment: Running a Korn shell script requires an instance of ksh to run.  Can you show exactly how you invoke the script in debug and non-debug mode?  What, if anything, do you have on the first line of your abs.ksh script?

Comment: i just use the -x option to run it in debug mode...

Comment: Can you just give me an idea about what exactly is "ksh"?Why it is working fine in non-debug mode? I will try to get the code in the meantime .....Thanks in advance

Comment: This is the first line of the code #!/usr/bin/ksh 
IS this causing ksh to be instantiated and sent to the server?

Comment: @Monojeet - ksh is required to run a script - it is the interpreter.  I don't clearly see what your problem is - you say it 'works' in non-debug mode, but in debug mode not - how does it fail?  Please give complete examples of working and non-working command lines - just saying 'I use -x' doesn't really give answerers much chance of figuring out what you're doing, or how to help you.

Comment: Try running the script with ksh explicitly: `ksh /app/fao/abs.ksh` and see if there is any difference.

Comment: 1] I am adding "-x" at the end of very first line making it in debug mode.Removal of "-x" gives non-debug mode
 #!/bin/ksh -x ---> in debug
Or   #!/bin/ksh  --->out of debug

2] My script has below first line
#!/bin/ksh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a standard "classic" Unix environment there may be multiple shells.  E.g. 'sh' the original Bourne shell, 'ksh' - the Korn shell, csh - the C shell,  bash, tcsh etc. etc..   A user login will have the default shell set per login.

The #! at the start of an executable script is an instruction to interpret & run the subsequent  text with the name of the program following the '#!'.

E.g. run this with perl

```
#!/bin/perl

<.. perl stuff ..>
```

So yes #!/usr/bin/ksh - will run the script with the command interpreter (shell) at that location.

Need more info. wrt how you run in debug mode.  I.e. are you typing 'ksh -x ...' or 'sh -x' - if so where is that on your search path. E.g. 'whence ksh' - maybe you're running with a different shell in debug mode.

Also which os is this ?